# Why is the negative entropy Lipschitz with respect to the $1$-norm (Over)?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, entropy

Let $\left\|x \right\| = \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\left|x^i\right|$ and $d\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x^i\ln x^i$ where $x\in R^n $ and $ \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x^i=1$

How to prove:
For all $x, x'$, $$\left| d\left(x\right)-d(x') \right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\left\|x-x' \right\|$$

I would appreciate it if you could give me any information about this. I had looked so hard but got nothing.

Thanks.

By the way, the above question is equivalent to the question below.
Let $\left\|x \right\| = \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\left|x^i\right|$ and $d\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x^i\ln x^i$, where $x\in \left\{R^n \mid x\ge0,\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x^i=1\right\}$
The question is how to prove $d_1\left(x\right)\ge \frac{1}{2}\left\|x-x_0\right\|$ where $x_0= \operatorname{argmin}_x \left\{d_1\left(x\right)\right\}$. Actually $x_0^i=\frac{1}{2},i=1,2,...,n$

Comment: Cross posted on Mathoverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126359/why-the-negative-entropy-is-lipshcitz-continue-with-one-norm

Comment: Does someone who conducts math career likes a spy or detective；-) I had already deleted it. A math researcher told me that if there is no answer after one or two weeks, I could post to overflow.

Comment: Why did you delete it then? Did you get your hint? If not, you should undelete it.

Comment: I happliy found the answer from a scribe of Ofer Dekel and  Albert Yu. http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse599s/12sp/scribes/lecture10.pdf It gave a method to prove it.

Comment: @abatkai Hi. The above link gives a hint. It shows a way to prove.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of $\pm H(p):=\mp\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\log(p_i)$ w.r.t $p_i$ is $g_i=\mp((1)\log(p_i) + p_i(1/p_i))=\mp(\log(p_i) + 1)$, and $\max_i |g_i| \le \log(n) + 1$. Thus $\|\nabla_p H(p)\|_\infty \le \log(n) + 1$ for all $p \in \Delta_n$. Thus $\pm H$ is $(\log(n) + 1)$-Lipschitz w.r.t to the dual of the $\ell_\infty$-norm, i.e w.r.t to the $\ell_1$-norm. Done.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like it can possibly be true, because the [Fannes-Audenaert bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fannes%E2%80%93Audenaert_inequality) can be saturated (see the example on that page showing that the bound is optimal), thereby providing an example of pairs of states such that no finite Lipschitz constant is possible - note that the binary entropy function $H(\{T,1-T\})$ has infinite derivative at $T=0$.

dohmatob's answer seems to be flawed because I don't see a justification for claiming that $|\log(p_i)+1| \leq \log(n)+1$: the probabilities $p_i$ can be arbitrarily close to zero, which causes $|\log(p_i)+1|$ to diverge. In fact this is essentially the key property that causes the entropy to not be Lipschitz continuous.